# How to get result on running thread from many activity on android?

Tags: android, multithreading

i have already get result from thread that running in same activity, but after change activity i cant get that result. is there any way to get that result ?
here my Thread, i get the result from `runOnUiThread`

```
private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
    private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
    private final InputStream mmInStream;
    private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

    public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
        mmSocket = socket;
        InputStream tmpIn = null;
        OutputStream tmpOut = null;

        // Get the input and output streams, using temp objects because
        // member streams are final
        try {
            tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
            tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) { }

        mmInStream = tmpIn;
        mmOutStream = tmpOut;
    }

    public void run() {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];  // buffer store for the stream
        int bytes; // bytes returned from read()

        // Keep listening to the InputStream until an exception occurs
        while (true) {
            try {
                // Read from the InputStream
                bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);
                final String s = new String(buffer);
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), s.toString(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        txtcomand.setText(s);
                        intent.putExtra("ct", s);
                    }
                });

                // Send the obtained bytes to the UI activity
                //  .obtainMessage(MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer)
                //         .sendToTarget();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    /* Call this from the main activity to send data to the remote device */
    public void write(byte[] bytes) {
        try {
            mmOutStream.write(bytes);
        } catch (IOException e) { }
    }

    /* Call this from the main activity to shutdown the connection */
    public void cancel() {
        try {
            mmSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) { }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use AsyncTask instead of your Thread implementation

Answer (score 0):

You could define an interface to communicate between different activitys or classes.

Just create the interface with methods that allow you to pass the data you need.

Then implement it on the receiver activity, when you create your second activity you need to pass the instance of the receiver activity and store it.

Then you can call that method and pass any parameter when you need.

Hope this helps.

Comment: can u give me some example of interface ?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend implementing a Service class instead of using a thread for your socket communication. A Service can run independently of your activities and different activities can communicate with your service in a number of ways.

For example i would implement a service and an event bus such as Otto (http://square.github.io/otto/) - its a few lines of code implementation. And then you can send your result without worrying about activities, and you activities/fragments can subscribe to those events. Its the easiest/safest way to communicate in your case, IMO, and you will have a nicely modular system.

Btw if you still want to use your thread, you can just add the event bus and use it for communication.

There are also other ways to pass that data. Interfaces for example, Broadcast receivers...